# Contador de pagina php ou javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, css3

Bom, não estou conseguindo usar o CSS @page para fazer a contagem das paginas na hora de imprimir, alguém sabe um método?

```
<style>
  @page{
    counter-increment: page;
  }
  .totalpag{
    content: counter(page);
  }
</style>
<span class="totalpag"></span>
```

É porque ta meio grande e confuso mas basicamente é uma tabela com thead, tbody e tfoot, quando eu imprimo fica o header certo as linhas e foot em cada pagina, porém não consigo colocar o total de paginas na ultima linha como mostra a print: [Imagem](http://prntscr.com/hbbl6d)

Comment: é porque ta meio grande e confuso mas basicamente é uma tabela com **thead, tbody  e tfoot**, quando eu imprimo fica o header bonitinho as linhas e foot em cada pagina, porém não consigo colocar o total de paginas na ultima linha como mostra a print: http://prntscr.com/hbbl6d

Comment: "A regra CSS '@page' é utilizada para modificar algumas propriedades CSS quando o documento for impresso. Você não pode mudar todas as propriedades CSS com '@page'. Você poderá somente mudar as margens, orphans, widows, e page breaks do documento. Na tentativa de mudar outra propriedade CSS, elas serão ignoradas." [Fonte: MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@page)